# Re-order array putting nulls at end C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to make an LRU, and keep track of the value order.

So lets say I have array `items = "P1", "P3", null, null`

- P4 shows up (items = `"P1", "P3", "P4", null`)
- P4 does not already exist, so I just add it to the lowest `null` index.
- But then P1 comes again, so P1's spot goes to `null` (items = `null, "P3", "P4", null`)
- I then need a way (**my question**) to shift everything like so  (items = `"P3", "P4", null, null`)
- Then add P1 at the lowest `null` index (items = `"P3", "P4", "P1", null`)
- And so on, keeping track of LRU

So I need to find a way to move all non-nulls to front of the array (in order).

I did find a post that used this `items = items.Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray();`, however this removes all `null`s, when I want to keep intact the array size.

How can I preserve my array size, while shifting all nulls to the end, and all non-nulls to the front (keeping the values in order still)

Comment: You don't want to be re-building an entire array from scratch, and repopulating every single item every time anything changes, ever.  That just won't scale.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/nakhli/6686251

Comment: You could mention that LRU means [least recently used](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms#LRU). // Why use an array? If you used a `List<string>` instead, you could just `.Remove("P1")` and then `.Add("P1")`. Remember that `.Remove` method is OK with doing no change to the `List<>` when the item is nowhere in there. It will be easier to implement. It will still be quite inefficient. If performance matters (like @Servy says), use some kind of [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Neat idea! Sorry I am still new C# and learning all the different data structures and what not. I ending up just adding a program counter, and I grab the lowest counter value to swap out values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just literally "First the non-null items, then the null items":

```
var nulls = items.Where(x => x == null);
var nonnulls = items.Where(x => x != null);
var result = nonnulls.Concat(nulls);
```

Or:

```
var result = items.OrderBy(x => x == null).ThenBy(x => x.SomeOtherKey);
```

Comment: OP might be looking for an array type.  They can use `.ToArray()` to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that doesn't create a new array.  It just rearranges the existing array.

```
static void MoveFront<T>(T[] arr) where T : class
{
    int ileft = 0;
    int iright = 1;

    while (iright < arr.Length)
    {
        T left = arr[ileft];
        T right = arr[iright];

        if (left == null && right != null)
        {
            Swap(arr, ileft++, iright++);
        }
        else if (left == null && right == null)
        {
            iright++;
        }
        else if (left != null && right != null)
        {
            ileft += 2;
            iright += 2;
        }
        else if (left != null && right == null)
        {
            ileft++;
            iright++;
        }
    }
}

static void Swap<T>(T[] arr, int left, int right)
{
    T temp = arr[left];
    arr[left] = arr[right];
    arr[right] = temp;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
string[] arr = { "a", null, "b", null, "c" };
MoveFront(arr);
```